# How to write tests for my models in MVC .NET (From Rails Background)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have previously developed in Rails. I found writing tests pretty easy, and I have recently moved to a project where MVC .NET is used for our main product.

I have figured out how to work with MVC .NET, but I still am not sure on how I should go around writing unit tests for my models. I will give a really quick dirty example on how I would write my unit test in rails:

```
describe "user.name_is_newton?" 

  context "user's name is newton" do
    before :each do
      @user = User.create(:name => "newton")
    end

    it { @user.name_is_newton?.should be_true }
  end    
end
```

The reason I am finding it hard to switch is because I am used to Rails providing a separate database for testing. It will (apparently) create a User entry in the test database behind the scenes and make it very easy to write the test. I am not sure how write a similar test in MVC .NET. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you wouldn't normally want to be working with a database at all for unit tests, but try and refactor so that you are testing methods that act on a IEnumerable<[entity]> or IQueryable<[entity]> or even just the Entity itself. That way your unit is just working on as general a 'thing' as possible. But maybe I'm telling you things you already know.

If you absolutely have to work on more complex objects you need to mock them, or again refactor to use an interface instead and just mock the interface.

I do have a library of useful MVC mocks, like HttpContextBase, HtmlHelper, HttpResponseBase, DbSet, and helpers like ShouldEqual. They're too long to paste in here unnecessarily, but ask and I'll happily supply them. They use Moq.

Your example above using Moq might be:

Method to test:

```
public User CreateUser(string name)
{
    return new User { Name = name };
}
```

Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void CreateUser_NameIsNewton()
{
     var user = CreateUser("Newton");
     Assert.AreEqual(user.Name, "Newton");
}
```

Comment: this might be a silly question, but what is the object User? Is it an entity in the database? Do we mock User?

Comment: @steveowen where did you get the MVC mocks from? Did you write them yourself or find them online? I'd like to see some examples of what they look like.

Comment: @Newton "User" would be the model you've created. It might be the entity in the database, or it might your own model you're using for display purposes. (It's best practice to not use database models for presentation duties.)

Comment: @Dty I've got them from all over the place, I think, and wrote some of them myself, but initially it was from Steve Sanderson's Pro ASP.Net MVC 2 Framework book, Ch9, Controllers And Actions.

Comment: @SteveOwen thanks. I may be missing a piece of information about MVC 3, but the way I have created the database models is using a DBContext, which has IDsets. I guess I would have to mock both of these, but your example seems much simpler. Do you not need to mock DBContext somewhere?

Comment: @Newton only if you're unit testing a method that relies on the DBContext. And you should really only be unit testing the DBContext if you want to test that a record has been submitted for changing/adding/deleting. It's better, cleaner and more general purpose if you code so that you are just working with an IEnumerable, ICollection, IList etc., instead of IDbSet. For instance, if you're testing that a method filters a collection (by id say), why not pass in the original, full list as an IQueryable, and return an IQueryable as the filtered result. Then test by passing in your own list.

Comment: @Newton Unit tests should be the smallest unit of work you can manage, and there's no need for a small method like that to be tied to the DBContext, when it could work with just a collection of entities instead. It does of course depend on what your method wants to do, but usually, if you're having to mock a DBContext you might be doing integration tests, not unit tests. Eg, making sure everything fits together rather than ensuring a method returns predictable and repeatable values.

Comment: @SteveOwen, I understand that we should abstract the database as much as possible, and only deal with abstract objects of User, for example. But we would need to test that the correct query to the database is taken place. My question is, how do we test that? I think I know what you are saying, and probably the confusion is that in my Rails experience, the simple unit test actually works as an integration test, since User.create actually queries the (fake) database. I guess I would have to write my own set of unit tests that mock the DBContext at a layer below perhaps